# smoothScroll plugin conflict with SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am using wave menu that is created by using

`<script src="js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>`

By default, menu is 3 line menu button , on click, it populates a menu like wave.

On adding another library to get smooth scroll, a wave is starting display on page that actually should appear on click 3 line menubutton
[image: wave menu]

On removing 
`<script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>`
it worlks normally

How can i solve this confliction?

[Demo](http://codepen.io/zeeshan55/pen/qqqZJv)

Comment: To help us, could you please turn your code into a working snippet or fiddle.  See [MCVE help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau

See this pen, i am getting this on screen without click on menu button 

http://codepen.io/zeeshan55/pen/qqqZJv